# Spring REST Controller should PUT JSON and then redirect to specified page

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-rest

I wrote a @RestController with one @PutMapping. Everything works technically fine. When the PutMapper is called, the JSON Object is rendered in my browser. But that's exactly the point what the customer doesn't want of course. What I'm trying to do is to send the JSON Object via PUT Method and then show a specified View. How can I handle this?

This is my RestController:

```
@RestController
public class UserRESTController {

private UserController userController;

@Autowired
public UserRESTController(UserController userController) {
    this.userController = userController;
}

@PutMapping("/admin/changeUser")
public UserModel changeUser(@ModelAttribute("user") @Valid UserModel user, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        model.addAttribute("error", true);
        userController.showUserToEdit(user.getUserId(), model);
    }

    model.addAttribute("editSuccess", true);
    model.addAttribute("userId", user.getUserId());
    model.addAttribute("userFirstName", user.getFirstName());
    model.addAttribute("userLastName", user.getLastName());
    userController.showUserList(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), model);
    return user;
}
}
```

The Line

```
userController.showUserList(Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), Optional.empty(), model);
```

calls another, non-REST-Controller, which simply renders a List of all users.
What can I do to get the user list after the JSON is sent?

Comment: I'm confused, you're writing a REST API but you want to return an HTML view? I think you're mixing two different things here. I would either handle the view client side using something like angular or react, or not use a rest controller but use spring MVC to return a view generated on the server side.

Comment: I was afraid that something like this comes up.... so I have no chance to keep my clients old spring mvc views and send data changes to the server via REST?

Comment: Sure you can write a REST API and have the browser send updates this way. It just doesn't make sense for that REST controller to return a new HTML view, it's no longer a REST API if it does.

Comment: Ok, as you've said above, I'm totally mixing things up. Of course the REST API is on the server and the frontend just consumes the REST Services. Thank you for the insight.